# Помогите с созданием файла с магическими методами Python

Tags: python

в задании нужно создать интерфейс для работы с файлами. Интерфейс должен предоставлять следующие возможности по работе с файлами:

- чтение из файла, метод read возвращает строку с текущим содержанием файла
- запись в файл, метод write принимает в качестве аргумента строку с новым содержанием файла
- сложение объектов типа File, результатом сложения является объект класса File, при этом создается новый файл и файловый объект, в котором содержимое второго файла добавляется к содержимому первого файла. Новый файл должен создаваться в директории, полученной с помощью функции tempfile.gettempdir. Для получения нового пути можно использовать os.path.join.
- возвращать в качестве строкового представления объекта класса File полный путь до файла
- поддерживать протокол итерации, причем итерация проходит по строкам файла

При создании экземпляра класса File в конструктор передается полный путь до файла на файловой системе. Если файла с таким путем не существует, он должен быть создан при инициализации.

Пример работы:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> from solution import File
>>> path_to_file = 'some_filename'
>>> os.path.exists(path_to_file)
False
>>> file_obj = File(path_to_file)
>>> os.path.exists(path_to_file)
True
>>> file_obj.read()
''
>>> file_obj.write('some text')
9
>>> file_obj.read()
'some text'
>>> file_obj.write('other text')
10
>>> file_obj.read()
'other text'
>>> file_obj_1 = File(path_to_file + '_1')
>>> file_obj_2 = File(path_to_file + '_2')
>>> file_obj_1.write('line 1\n')
7
>>> file_obj_2.write('line 2\n')
7
>>> new_file_obj = file_obj_1 + file_obj_2
>>> isinstance(new_file_obj, File)
True
>>> print(new_file_obj)
C:\Users\Media\AppData\Local\Temp\71b9e7b695f64d85a7488f07f2bc051c
>>> for line in new_file_obj:
....    print(ascii(line))  
'line 1\n'
'line 2\n'
>>>
```

Я отправил на проверку код, автопроверка выдала следующее:

```
Total tests: 36. Tests failed: 1, Errors: 0. Total time: 0.367.
Failed test - test_14.
 assert '/tmp' == ''
      + /tmp
E   AssertionError: Тест 14. При сложении двух экземпляров класса File новый файл должен создаваться в директории, полученной с помощью tempfile.gettempdir.
```

Отправленный код:

```
from os.path import exists, dirname, join
import uuid


class File:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.current_position = 0

        if not exists(self.path):
            open(self.path, 'w').close()

    def write(self, content):
        with open(self.path, 'w') as f:
            return f.write(content)

    def read(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r') as f:
            return f.read()

    def __add__(self, obj):
        new_path = join(
            gettempdir(self.path),
            str(uuid.uuid4().hex)
        )
        new_file = type(self)(new_path)
        new_file.write(self.read() + obj.read())

        return new_file

    def __str__(self):
        return self.path

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r') as f:
            f.seek(self.current_position)

            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                self.current_position = 0
                raise StopIteration('EOF')

            self.current_position = f.tell()

            return line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tempfile

def __add__(self, obj):
        new_path = join(tempfile.gettempdir(), str(uuid.uuid4()))
        new_file = type(self)(new_path)
        new_file.write(self.read() + obj.read())

        return new_file
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]